# Using streaming with Node and mssql

Tags: node.js, sql-server, express

I've searched a lot but cannot find a solid example of using a stream from mssql for Node

Data Controller

```
//Data controller used to query and update the database
var sql = require('mssql');

//Config data for database connection
var config = {
    user: '',
    password: '',
    server: '',
    stream: true,
    database: ''
};  

module.exports.queryDatabase = function(req, res, sqlQueryString) {
    var contactList = [];
    var connection = new sql.Connection(config, function(err) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            var request = new sql.Request(connection);
            request.query(sqlQueryString);
            request.on('row', function(row) {
            });
    connection.close();
        }
    });
};
```

Page Render Controller:

```
var data = require(./data);
    module.exports.renderInvestorsPage = function(req, res) {
    buildQuery = 'SELECT contact_info.last_name, \
                  contact_info.first_name, \
                  contact_info.contact_key, \
                  contact_info.work, \
                  contact_info.home, \
                  contact_info.email \
                  FROM contact_info \
                  WHERE contact_info.investor = 1';
    investorResults = data.queryDatabase(req, res, buildQuery);
    console.log(investorResults);
    res.render('investors', {title: 'Investors'});
};
```

View:

```
extends layout

block content
    div.row
        div.col-lg-12
        h1.page-header #{title}
    div.row
        table
            tr
                th Last Name
                th First Name
                th Work Phone
                th Home Phone
                th Email
            tbody
                each investor in investorResults
                    td= investor.last_name
                    td= investor.first_name
                    td= investor.work
                    td= investor.home
                    td= investor.email
```

I'm stumped as to why I can't use the query results in this manner. It seems the issue has to be with using the streaming option from mssql but reluctantly I have to use the stream since I'm working with 10,000 contacts...

Comment: No human is going to read 10000 rows in a table. Don't load stuff you can't display in the first place. Web sites use paging and virtualized scrolling to give the illusion of seamless scrolling without actually loading all the data

Comment: Loading 10K rows would make sense if you wanted to export the data as a CSV or Excel file. In that case you should use a library that produces proper CSVs or `xlsx` files instead of creating an HTML table that may or *may not* be readable by Excel or Libre Calc. `xlsx` is a zip containing XML files which means you *don't* need Excel installed on the server to create a real Excel file

Answer (score 0):

If you are displaying this data, implement paging in a stored proc and then grab blocks of data to display on the screen. The only reason you should return that many records at one time is for a report or to export.  A report format assumes a high likely hood of printing or exporting.